# Neo4J Spatial within distance returns only exact matches

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-spatial

Added data to the neo4j using the below script. The data gets added successfully but there is problem with the querying. The query works only if i give the exact lat and long of a node in the database. Any other coords results in an empty set.

```
import csv
import requests
import json

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

# Create geom index
url = "http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/"
payload= {
  "name" : "geom",
  "config" : {
    "provider" : "spatial",
    "geometry_type" : "point",
    "lat" : "lat",
    "lon" : "lon"
  }
}

r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers, auth=('neo4j', 'thanks123'))

with open('/home/haripriya/workspace/ContentMatching/src/main/resources/coords.csv', 'rb') as f:   # read data file
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
    # create airport node
    url = "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node"
    payload = {'name': row[0], 'street': row[1], 'city': row[2], 'state': row[3], 'pin': row[4], 'lon': float(row[5]), 'lat': float(row[6])}
    r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers, auth=('neo4j', 'thanks123'))
    node = r.json()['self']

    #add node to geom index
    url = "http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/geom"
    payload = {'value': 'dummy', 'key': 'dummy', 'uri': node}
    r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers, auth=('neo4j', 'thanks123'))

    #add node to Spatial index
    url = "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/addNodeToLayer"
    payload = {'layer': 'geom', 'node': node}
    r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers, auth=('neo4j', 'thanks123'))
```

example nodes:
A   29.6490287781   -98.4621124268
B   30.2107849121   -95.7507781982

START n=node:geom('withinDistance:[29.6490287781, -98.4621124268, 50.0]') RETURN n  returns node A but

START n=node:geom('withinDistance:[29.6490287780, -98.4621124260, 50.0]') RETURN n returns empty set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a similar question already posted on stackoverflow. The answer had helped. Please find the link below:

[Neo4j Spatial return only one node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25017295/neo4j-spatial-return-only-one-node?rq=1)

Thanks!